# Как кастомизировать форму для WP?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, плагин, формы, шорткод

На сайте нужна форма для отправки отзывов, удалось создать форму через плагин WPforms. Через шорт-код вставил на сайт, но теперь вопрос, как кастомизировать форму(на скрине показана, как она выглядит)? Возможно я что-то не понимаю, и Вы сможете посоветовать другой плагин или вообще другое решение проблем, заранее благодарю[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RMg0.png)

Comment: У этого плагина должны быть стили из коробки, проверьте подключены ли они у вас

Comment: Дополню @Dantessss: помимо стилей плагина, вы можете перезаписать всё стилевой оформление через собственный файл стилей. Найдите через консоль разработчика присвоенные css-классы всем элементам формы и переопределите их.